# sitk.N4BiasFieldCorrectionImageFilter() Proper Usage

Tags: simpleitk

I am trying to apply the N4ITKBiasFieldCorrectionImageFilter from SimpleITK, to an MRI scan as a pre-processing step. From what I've gathered this can be executed in 3D and I've been applying it with this code:

```
corrector = sitk.N4BiasFieldCorrectionImageFilter()

maskImage=sitk.OtsuThreshold(Original_scan, 0, 1, 200)   
I = sitk.Cast( Original_scan, sitk.sitkFloat32 )
BiasCorrected_scan=corrector.Execute(I,maskImage)
```

I keep getting the same Error eventually as it executes the function:

```
    RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK N4BiasFieldCorrectionImageFilter_Execute: c:\d\vs14-win64-pkg\simpleitk-build\itk-prefix\include\itk-4.11\itkImageToImageFilter.hxx:250:
itk::ERROR: SubtractImageFilter(0000021C00CCEEA0): Inputs do not occupy the same physical space! 
InputImage Origin: [1.2708700e+02, -1.5783400e+02, 9.0149000e+01], InputImage_1 Origin: [6.5250000e+01, -5.4894173e+01, 5.4894173e+01]
    Tolerance: 4.2969999e-05
InputImage Spacing: [4.2969999e-01, 4.2969999e-01, 3.0000000e+00], InputImage_1 Spacing: [5.4894173e+01, 5.4894173e+01, 6.5250000e+01]
    Tolerance: 4.2969999e-05
```

Does anybody have experience executing this filter?

PS. even if I set origin and spacing before executing the filter, the error happens.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Please also include your image size and the direction cosine matrix.

Answer (score 0):

That should not happen. Your data is either odd some how or the is a small bug in the filter.

A quick hack would be to call sitk::ProcessObject::SetGlobalDefaultCoordinateTolerance (double) to a large enough number as to hide this error.

Answer (score 0):

try to set defined MaximunNumberOfIterations:::

```
corrector = sitk.N4BiasFieldCorrectionImageFilter()

numberFittingLevels = 4

numberOfIteration = [50] (array)

corrector.SetMaximumNumberOfIterations(numberOfIteration * numberFittingLevels)
```

set lower values till your tolerance Value is accepted